# Cannot start conda.exe when running PowerShell - invalid command 'hook'?

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my PC and it got the following error when starting PowerShell?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

invalid command 'hook'
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At \\INTRANET\AMER\User\0001\X\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:95
+ ... onda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

And in the file `My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\users\X\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

Comment: I don't know Anaconda, but either way you should explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Every time it shows the error message when I open a PowerShell command window after install Anaconda. I want to get rid of the error. Also I want to use Python/Anaconda in PowerShell.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me what he is trying to do here - start Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

your conda version needs upgraded, try this:conda upgrade -n base -c defaults --override-channels conda